# How to hide navigation bar in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, screen

Basically that's the question. What can I do to hide the navigation bar when I run an app in a phone that does not have physical home buttons? By the way I'm running android 5 (I don't know if that changes anything.)

If you know how to do it please answer :)

Answer (score 25):

I know it's an old question, but to anyone who finds their way here, libGDX now has a very easy way to do this. Simply set this field in the AndroidLauncher class.

```
config.useImmersiveMode = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of date, LibGDX does not have an abstraction for hiding the navigation bar unlike the status bar. (It has a control for status bar in the [AndroidApplicationConfiguration](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html) class.) You should do the hiding in your wrapper application for Android.

Here you go with the link: [Hiding the Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [PixNB Blog](http://www.pixnbgames.com/blog/libgdx/how-to-hide-virtual-buttons-in-android-libgdx/) has your answer.

The steps are :
Add hideVirtualButtons() method to AndroidLauncher.java :

```
    @TargetApi(19)
private void hideVirtualButtons() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
              View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

call hideVirtualButtons from onCreate() in AndroidLauncher.java:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ....
    // In KITKAT (4.4) and next releases, hide the virtual buttons
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        hideVirtualButtons();
    }
}
```

And override the function onWindowFocusChanged() within AndroidLauncher.java:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        // In KITKAT (4.4) and next releases, hide the virtual buttons
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            hideVirtualButtons();
        }
    }
}
```

Visit the [blog](http://www.pixnbgames.com/blog/libgdx/how-to-hide-virtual-buttons-in-android-libgdx/) if you need some explaination.